# AWS Lambda - Fluentd instead of CloudWatch possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logging, aws-lambda, fluentd

I want to move my logging for AWS Lambda from CloudWatch to Elasticsearch and Kibana, using Fluentd. I understand that I need to use Lambda outputs as an input to Fluentd, which I already have set up. All my Lambda functions are in Python.

Is it possible to capture Lambda output with Fluentd without additional plugins, i.e. using just tail? I do not see any Lambda input plugin in [the Fluentd list](https://www.fluentd.org/plugins/all), only the output one. If not, is there any possible workaround, or do I have to write plugin specifically for this? Or would simply inserting data into Elasticsearch suffice, omitting Fluentd altogether?

EDIT: to clarify, I want to get rid of CloudWatch, with no streaming to it at all.

Comment: I don't think Fluentd is the correct tool here. I suggest looking at a solution like the one in this blog post https://epsagon.com/development/stream-aws-lambda-logs-to-elasticsearch/ The solution detailed there is actually a common pattern used for anything that logs to CloudWatch Logs that also needs to go to Elasticsearch, not just Lambda log output.

Comment: @MarkB I want to not use CloudWatch at all, maybe this wasn't clear enough in my question. This is why I rejected this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do it without additional 'plugins' but you can do it with a Lambda Extension.

This code sample gives you an example.

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-extensions/tree/main/python-example-elasticsearch-extension